# Resources for PRO: Microsoft SharePoint 2010, Administrator, 070 668 Exam

Tags: 2010, learning, exams

Appreciate if you could list the reading materials for this exam.

Comment: I set this open question to Community Wiki.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to know what you will learn and take an exam via [skill measured section](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?id=70-668#tab2) then purchase a course at [Microsoft Learning](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/exam.aspx?id=70-668#tab3).

Below are the references I can give you:

- [SharePoint 2010 Administration books in Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?field-keywords=sharepoint%202010%20administration&url=search-alias=stripbooks&x=0&y=0).
- [SharePoint 2010 Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428287.aspx)

They are sufficient for your exam.

Comment: This video really helped. http://mediadl.microsoft.com/mediadl/www/l/learning/video/exams/Exam_70-668_Microsoft_SharePoint_2010_Administrator.wmv

Answer (score 0):

Some excellent books for the exam are

1. [Professional SharePoint 2010 Administration](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470533331)
2. [Beginning SharePoint 2010 Administration](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470597127)

However I would still prefer the first book as it is an excellent resource which is well in-line to passing the exam credentials.