# List of 70-488 exam resources

Tags: 2013, certification, exams

What have you used to prepare for the 70-488 certification exam?  I need to take it by the end of the month.

I'm planning on going through the self-paced training offered by Microsoft at this link:

http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-microsoft-sharepoint-server-2013-core-solutions-jump-start

What else should I be doing to prepare for this exam?  I work with SharePoint 2013 daily, but there seem to be a lot of topics covered on this exam that I haven't had a need to learn.

I'm going to add links here as I find things that seem useful.

Apparently there was a test prep book in the making, but something happened between Microsoft and the publisher, and the book never got published.  Becky Bertram was writing the book, and she posted some notes on her site:
http://www.savtechsol.com/Education/BeckysBlog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=211

Comment: I have a copy of that book (for 70-488) so it must have been published in at least a small edition

Comment: Here is the ISBN number: 9780735681767, but it looks like the edition might be sold out (released 2014-01)

Comment: Robert Lindgren, could you respond?  How is this opinion based?  I'm just looking for resources.  And that book that you linked to is not available at the first forty stores in a Google search.  So I still need some help.

Comment: Your question is opinion based because there is no one true answer to it that will work for all people. All people study in their own ways and have different skills coming in to the new task of taking this certifications. Hence, every member of this site could post different answers, all only being based on their own opinions

Comment: Why don't you close these questions down as well?   http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27290/sharepoint-developer-exam-70-573?rq=1
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11612/list-of-70-573-exam-resources
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105764/good-books-regarding-sharepoint-2013-exam-70-331?rq=1
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10942/is-there-a-recommended-order-in-which-to-take-the-sharepoint-2010-exams?rq=1
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20114/resources-for-pro-microsoft-sharepoint-2010-administrator-070-668-exam?rq=1

Comment: All of the examples are either closed, or community wikis. Do you want your question to be converted to a community wiki?

Comment: yes please.  just open it back up.

Comment: Ok, community-wiki it is! Good luck with your studies